# Proxy Configuration in Java web applicaiton

Tags: java, proxy, struts

How do i configure my java web applicaiton to use proxy configurations? I have been given ipaddress and port number on which my application should send request to utilize internet usage. I have tried following ways:

1) [How do I configure proxy settings for Java?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml)

2) Setting System Properties in Code: I added following configuration in my controller servlet, which starts all cron jobs when application starts:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
   System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
```

[source](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-proxy-setting-java-setting-proxy-java/)

Both ways not working for me, however these proxy configuration works fine in browser.

I wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve it? Some config file settings? Thanks

Comment: Did you add proxyset property to true systemSettings.put("proxySet", "true");

Comment: It works for java core classes, but if the application uses some 3rd party libraries, setting proxy may not be so easy. Sometimes it needs to be set programatically.

Comment: @Looser You mean `System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true");` yes i did. but no luck.

Comment: @agad yes i'm calling third party web service.

Comment: @Eez Important is how you call it (see e.g. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e571 for appache http client)